# Neo4j and Multiple Items, Nested Relationships

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am not sure how to phrase this question as I don't even know what it's called but I will try.

You can imagine that I have the following graph representation and relationships in my neo4j instance:

[image]

The question I want to ask Neo4j is the below: What are the **movies** that **only** Agency-A actors **acted**?

This is a simple sample though. In my case, I have thousands of actors who joined an agent and thousands of movies that an actor potentially acted.

PS: I would also appreciate if you can tell me the name of the thing I am trying to do :)

### Update

I was able to have something solid working. Here is the data set:

```
CREATE (AgencyA:Agency {name: 'Agency-A'})
CREATE (Actor1:Person {name: 'Actor-1'})
CREATE (Actor2:Person {name: 'Actor-2'})
CREATE (Actor3:Person {name: 'Actor-3'})
CREATE (Actor4:Person {name: 'Actor-4'})
CREATE (Actor5:Person {name: 'Actor-5'})
CREATE 
  (AgencyA)-[:ACQUIRED]->(Actor1), 
  (AgencyA)-[:ACQUIRED]->(Actor3), 
  (AgencyA)-[:ACQUIRED]->(Actor5)

CREATE (MovieA:Movie {name: "Movie-A"})
CREATE (MovieB:Movie {name: "Movie-B"})
CREATE (MovieC:Movie {name: "Movie-C"})

CREATE 
  (MovieA)-[:EMPLOYED]->(Actor1),
  (MovieA)-[:EMPLOYED]->(Actor5),
  (MovieB)-[:EMPLOYED]->(Actor1),
  (MovieB)-[:EMPLOYED]->(Actor3),
  (MovieB)-[:EMPLOYED]->(Actor5),
  (MovieC)-[:EMPLOYED]->(Actor2),
  (MovieC)-[:EMPLOYED]->(Actor5)
```

Here is the query:

```
MATCH (agency:Agency {name:"Agency-A"})-[:ACQUIRED]->(actor:Person)<-[:EMPLOYED]-(movie:Movie)
RETURN distinct movie.name
```

The result:

> Movie-C
>
> Movie-B
>
> Movie-A

which is not what I want to get out. What I am interested in is the movie where only Agency-A actors have been employed, not any other actor. So, the result should be:

> Movie-A
>
> Movie-B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cypher this is dead easy :)

```
MATCH (agency:Agency {name:"AgencyA"})<-[:JOINED]-(actor:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie:Movie)
RETURN distinct movie.name
```

If an Actor might have joined the same agency multiple times (thus have more than one `JOINED` relationship to the same agency), you would distinct them before connecting the movies :

```
MATCH (agency:Agency {name:"AgencyA"})<-[:JOINED]-(actor:Actor)
WITH distinct actor as actor
MATCH (actor)-[:ACTED]->(movie:Movie)
RETURN distinct movie.name
```

---

**UPDATE**

After the clarification that no other persons could have played in a Movie where Agency-A people have been employed, this is a working query :

```
MATCH (agency:Agency { name:"Agency-A" })-[:ACQUIRED]->(actor:Person)<-[:EMPLOYED]-(movie:Movie)
WITH DISTINCT movie, collect(actor) AS actors
MATCH (movie)-[:EMPLOYED]->(allemployees:Person)
WITH movie, actors, count(allemployees) AS c
WHERE c = size(actors)
RETURN movie.name
```

Here, we are comparing the total number of the movie employees to the size of employees firstly matched by the Agency-A

You can test it here :

http://console.neo4j.org/r/s9t6en

Comment: Really appreciated it, thx. Will give this a go now. I am guessing relationship directions don't matter. E.g. If I have [this graph model](http://i.imgur.com/9IPCvco.png) instead, would that be a completely different query?

Comment: Relationships directions don't matter at query time no. But I would add them in the query though.

Comment: I assume the query would like this for this: `MATCH (agency:Agency {name:"AgencyA"})->[:ACQUIRED]-(actor:Actor)-[:EMPLOYED]<-(movie:Movie)
RETURN distinct movie.name`

Comment: hmm, tried my query and got a failure. this is the data set: https://gist.github.com/tugberkugurlu/14ed82ade5308fcd184f#file-agency-movie-person-cypher

Comment: Multiple things : The name of the agency was not good, the labels are not Actor but Person, the arrows for the relationships were not on the right place. Try this : `MATCH (agency:Agency { name:"Agency-A" })-[:ACQUIRED]-(actor:Person)-[:EMPLOYED]-(movie:Movie)
RETURN DISTINCT movie.name` - demo here : http://console.neo4j.org/r/839b0e

Comment: thx, tried that (in fact, I was able to figure that out myself which I guess a good sign that I am learning :)) and it turned out that that is not what I want :( Can you see the update on the question? sorry that the question might have been a bit unclear.

Comment: Well your dataset is wrong then, actors 1, 3 and 5 have been acquired by Agency-A, and they played in 3 different movies, so the result is good here.

Comment: This should make it clear: *What I am interested in is the movie where only Agency-A actors have been employed, **not any other actor**.* So, the movie employees should solely consist of Agency-A actors.

Comment: This was clear. Agency-A actors are Actor1, Actor3, Actor5, right ? Actor1 has been employed in Movie A and MovieB, Actor3 has been employed in MovieB and Actor5 has been employed in MovieC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97690/discussion-between-tugberk-and-christophe-willemsen).